# Scala - How to Combine EitherT with Either in For Comprehension

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Suppose I have the following setting:

```
def foo: Either[Error, A] = ???
def bar: EitherT[Future, Error, B] = ???
case class Baz(a: A, b: B)
```

How can I use for comprehension to instantiate the class `Baz`? I tried with:

```
val res = for {
  a <- foo
  b <- bar
} yield Baz(a, b)
```

but, the result has type `Either[Error, Nothing]`. I don't know what is the right return type in this case, but obviously I don't want `Nothing`...

What is the right way to combine `Either` and `EitherT` in for comprehension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `EitherT.fromEither` function to create `EitherT` from `Either`

```
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

def foo[A]: Either[Error, A] = ???
def bar[B]: EitherT[Future, Error, B] = ???
case class Baz[A, B](a: A, b: B)

def res[A, B] = for {
  a <- EitherT.fromEither[Future](foo[A])
  b <- bar[B]
} yield Baz(a, b)
```