# Cats - EitherT - Diverging Implicit Expansion in for comprehension w/o explicit typing?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Trying to understand a way to do this without noisy explicit typing.

If I do the following:

```scala
// here maybeUser is Either[ServiceError, User]
// cacheService.remove(user) returns EitherT[Future, ServiceError, Unit]

def blah(): EitherT[Future, ServiceError, Unit] = {
    for {
      user <- EitherT.fromEither(maybeUser)
      _    <- cacheService
               .remove(user)
    } yield ()
}
```

This will return the following error:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type cats.kernel.Order[A]
[error] starting with value catsKernelStdOrderForFiniteDuration in trait FiniteDurationInstances
[error]       user <- EitherT.fromEither(maybeUser)
```

If I explicitly (noisy) type this, it works:

```
def blah(): EitherT[Future, ServiceError, Unit] = {
    for {
      user <- EitherT.fromEither(maybeUser):EitherT[Future, ServiceError, User]
      _    <- cacheService
               .remove(maybeUser)
    } yield ()
}
```

But explicitly typing becomes tiresome after awhile, especially in other (larger) parts of the code. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `EitherT.fromEither[Future](maybeUser)` say? Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086992/scala-how-to-combine-eithert-with-either-in-for-comprehension) shows the shorter syntax.

Comment: Facepalm. This works and is totally obvious.  Apologies for the duplicated question.